# Register for Apple Push Notifications

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, push-notification

My question is I used the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

But it never shows the alert asking the user if he want to receive push notifications.

I configured my provisioning profile on App ID for push notifications enabled for development. I downloaded the certificate and provisioning profile and added it, and then, running on iPad mini I never receive the alert. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to checkout if you get an error on

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error

and in case which one?

Comment: Yes i have implemented that delegate and it is being called. it gives following error: Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x1ed78700 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great tutorial, it's all you need to know: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Answer (score 0):

Did you receive the alert to ask if you authorised push once?
I've noticed that after the first time it will not ask again. If this is the case completely remove the app from your device and you might see it again the first time you start up.

Personally I would recommend using Parse.com or Urban Airship for push - both are very good.

Comment: No i never get that alert, i searched google and tried multiple scenarios like i deleted the appliction installed again, i deleted application restarted the device, and even changed the device to iphone 5 :) no luck

Answer (score 0):

Ok, given the error you got in the fail callback, it may be a problem with the certificate.

Do the following:

- In the iOS provisioning portal, check that you have an App Id that is enabled for push notifications
- Still in the provisioning portal, check that the povisioning profile you are using is connected to the App Id enabled for push notification
- In you project, check whether the Code Signing Identity you for the current target use the right profile

Comment: Yes i have done all those steps. I was trying to configure an older App ID to push notifications that had the same bundle identifier as my application, i tried changeing my bundle identifier n created a new App ID now it is working fine. May be older app id was creating problem.